# Wrangler - select data

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

After importing the pipeline from downloaded json, 
when I click on Wrangle properties, I get the below unable load page.
How do I modify the data for wrangler?

Thanks,
Aruna Jayabalu

Comment: Could you provide screenshot of the problem (when clicking on Wrangler property)? What does your pipeline do?

Comment: Aruna: Where did you export the pipeline. If it is from a different environment than what you are importing then its a known issue. Wrangler (under the hood) stores the workspace where you applied all your transformations. When you import it to a new environment it will not be able to load the same workspace. I believe that is the problem you are seeing. Can you access your source in the new environment? Creating a Source -> Wrangler is pretty simple if you have access to your wrangler source